# Add values to dictionary key using loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a large database from the following type:

```
data = {
    "2": {"overall": 172, "buy": 172, "name": "ben", "id": 2, "sell": 172},
    "3": {"overall": 173, "buy": 173, "name": "dan", "id": 3, "sell": 173},
    "4": {"overall": 174, "buy": 174, "name": "josh", "id": 4, "sell": 174},
    ...
```

and so on for about 10k rows.

Then, I created a loop to find if inside this `dict()` there are specific names:
I used the next loop

```
items = ["ben","josh"]

Database = dict()
Database = {"Buying_Price": "", "Selling_Price": ""}
for masterkey, mastervalue in data.items():
    if mastervalue['name'] in items:
        Database["Name"] = Database["Name"].append(mastervalue['name'])
        Database["Buying_Price"] = Database["Buying_Price"].append(mastervalue['buy'])
        Database["Selling_Price"] = Database["Selling_Price"].append(mastervalue['sell'])
```

However, I'm getting the next error:

```
Database["Buying_Price"] = Database["Buying_Price"].append(mastervalue['buy_average'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

My goal is to obtain a dict names Database with 2 keys: `Buying_Price,Selling_Price` where in each one I will have the following:

```
Buying_Price = {"ben":172,"josh":174}
Sellng_Price = {"ben":172,"josh":174}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused. Is your program running without crashing and producing the wrong results ("only the value of the last item as for 'josh' ")? Or is it crashing and producing no results ("Im getting the next error")? Or... Both, somehow? Do you have a try-except you're not showing us?

Comment: It looks like you are... trying to "append" a string to another string! [exactly as the error says], can you specify what you want as the output?

Comment: You have a lot of problems with the code, but the one you are referring to in the post is that you have defined `Database["Buying_Price"]` as a string and string object does not have the `.append()` method, only lists do.

Comment: Is there any suggestion then how to obtain the result im looking for?

Comment: @Ben what result are you looking for?

Comment: updated in the post what im trying to get.

Comment: @Ben please post exactly what output you want, formatted like the `data` dict

Comment: @Ben, your last post that you deleted, this script may help: https://repl.it/@downshift/BouncyStrongHoneyeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a nested `dict`.

```
items = ["ben", "josh"]

new_database = {"Buying_Price": {}, "Selling_Price": {}}

for key, row in data.items():
    name = row["name"]

    if name in items:
        new_database["Buying_Price"][name] = row["buy"]
        new_database["Selling_Price"][name] = row["sell"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with the code you posted, so we'll go line by line and fix them:

```
items = ["ben", "josh"]

Database = dict()
Database = {"Buying_Price": "", "Selling_Price": ""}
for masterkey, mastervalue in data.items():
    if mastervalue['name'] in items:
        Database["Name"] = Database["Name"].append(mastervalue['name'])
        Database["Buying_Price"] = Database["Buying_Price"].append(mastervalue['buy_average'])
        Database["Selling_Price"] = Database["Selling_Price"].append(mastervalue['sell_average'])
```

1. In Python, you don't need to define the object type
   explicitly and then assign its value, so it means that `Database =
   dict()` is redundant since you already define this to be a
   dictionary the line below.
2. You intend to aggregate your results of the `if` statement
   so both `Buying_Price` and `Selling_Price` should be defined as lists and not as strings. You can either do it by assigning a `[]`
   value or the literal `list()`.
3. According to your data structure, you don't have the
   `buy_average` and `sell_average` keys, only `buy` and `sell` so make sure you use the correct keys.
4. You don't need to re-assign your list value when using the
   `append()` method, it's the object's method so it will update the object in-place.
5. You didn't set what `Name` is in your `Database` object and
   yet you're trying to append values to it.

Overall, the code should roughly look like this:

```
items = ["ben","josh"]

Database = {"Buying_Price": [], "Selling_Price": [], "Name": []}
for masterkey, mastervalue in data.items():
    if mastervalue['name'] in items:
        Database["Name"].append(mastervalue['name'])
        Database["Buying_Price"].append(mastervalue['buy'])
        Database["Selling_Price"].append(mastervalue['sell'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Database = {"Buying_Price": "", "Selling_Price": ""}`, you are defining the key `Buying_Price` as `""` : meaning a string. You are trying to use the `.append()` list method into a string, hence the error `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`.

We do not know the output you want, but seeing how you want to compute your data, I suggest you do :

```
Database = {"Name" : [], "Buying_Price": [], "Selling_Price": []}
```

instead of the original...

```
Database = {"Buying_Price": "", "Selling_Price": ""}
```

This way, you will be able to append your data `Name`, `Buying_Price`, and `Selling_Price` at the same time, and you'll be able to make search and access data of all the arrays using the index of only one.

---

I haven't paid attention, but you are badly appending your data to your dict.

`.append()` will work **in-place**, meaning that you should do :

```
Database["Name"].append(mastervalue['name'])
```

instead of

```
Database["Name"] = Database["Name"].append(mastervalue['name'])
```

Comment: then i get: Database["Buying_Price"] = Database["Buying_Price"].append(mastervalue['buy'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Yes, because `.append()` returns `None`. Remove the assignment from those statement